# ATEASY software development environment formatted string

Tags: string, char, basic

Lets say i have a `char[100]` which is formatted like this: `“%d,%d,%d,%.2f,%.2f”`.

What is the best way in ATEASY to get all 5 varible values? ( `long,long,long,float, float`).

I wanted to work with `Split(sStr,",")` but it only works with `String` type.

Comment: What is special about ATEASY here?

Comment: ATEASY is a test executive and it is not in c, its in visual basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)` func in this form:

```
sscanf(str, "%d, %d, %d, %lf, %lf", lLong1, lLong2, lLong3, dDouble1, dDouble2)
```

In order to use this function you must add MSVCRT library to your libraries

Which is in:

`C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll`.